# QtQuick2 and C++ : Using a Repeater

Tags: c++, qt5, qtquick2

I'm using Qt 5.0.2 and QtQuick 2.0 to try building a very simple QML application, displaying tiles.

I want the tiles to be dynamically created with a repeater, interfacing C++.

I found an example on how to do it (`MineHunt`), but this example is using QtQuick 1 and Qt 4.7.

Here is my code :

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import "tiles"

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Grid {

        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.margins: 5
        columns: 3
        spacing: 10

        Repeater {
            id: repeater
            model: tiles
            delegate: tile
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

This file imports a folder named `tiles` containing another QML file named `tile.qml` which contains the following code :

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: tile
    width: 100
    height: 62
    color: "#ff0303"

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            var row = Math.floor(index / 3)
            var col = index - (Math.floor(index / 3) * 3)
            play(row, col)
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a class which implements methods needed to provide the `tiles` model.

It compiles fine but when I run it, I get the following error :

```
ReferenceError: tile is not defined
```

What's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> delegate: tile
> ```

This is wrong because there's no "tile" name defined in the current scope. You probably want to instantiate a tile component there, so you need:

```
delegate: tile {}
```

This is *also* wrong for another reason: type names must start with capital letters. So:

```
delegate: Tile {}
```

This is correct, but it won't work as is because QML has no idea where to find the `Tile` type. You need to add a `qmldir` file inside your `tiles` subdirectory containing something like this

```
module tiles
Tile 1.0 tile.qml
```

Comment: I added a `qmldir` file as you mentioned and changed the delegate line to `delegate: Tile {}`, but Qt Creator underlines this line with the error `Unknown component (M300)`. I tried to add an import command : `import "tiles/tile.qml" 1.0` but I still get the error. Any idea ?

Comment: I don't know about Creator (which might be choking on the types for other reasons), but by doing the modifications I told you I'm able to run this code with qmlscene: http://pastebin.com/jcx7cD7P

Comment: By the way, if you dig into Creator's documentation, there should be some tips about how to make it see your user-defined QML types (it should involve [generating a qmltypes file](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html), but I'm not 100% sure)